# syntax error in main simple c program osx using make

Tags: c, macos

This is a n00b question and I've seen an answer that does not help me.

I'm running a simple c program (firsty.c) written in textmate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hi world.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I've entered the following into the terminal with the following results:

```
$ make firsty.c
make: Nothing to be done for `firsty.c'.
$ ./firsty.c
./firsty.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./firsty.c: line 3: `int main()'
```

probably something simple, but I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Try using int main(int argc, char *argv[]) as the main prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make firsty.c` isn't doing anything at all. Try instead `make firsty`, and then `./firsty`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute the source file. You need to execute the binary file which was hopefully built by make.

I do not know what your makefile is doing, however if it's something like `gcc firsty.c` the binary output file will be named `a.out` by default. Use `gcc -o executable_name_here` to have differently named output file (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Unix (osx at this time) is considering executable file a script, and tries to execute it. On other thing to do would be to remove executable permissions from your source file and then you will not be able to run it.

Comment: But, why would someone get a syntax error while trying to execute a source file?

Comment: Is the new file a.out?  If so is this an osx thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think u have not created any Makefile which is used by make command to compile the given source file(s)... so try to write a makefile(http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) else try to compile as...

```
gcc firsty.c -o firstly
```

then u'll get the executable file in the same directory & u can execute it as

```
./firstly
```

Answer (score 0):

take care of the '#'. when you excute a source code file, the OS maybe excute it with the shell.  So we get the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try make firsty, it will work and will make a executable with a name firstly.

If this oes not work, try make ./firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while doing a make as such you need to supply the name of file only and not the extension as .c
The output file is created with the name of file and it will search for corresponding .c file to compile. 
In your case

```
 make firsty
```

This will look for firsty.c to be compiled and create an output file with name firsty.